# How to say what permission a user is missing discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Ive got a command which requires a specific permission and i want to say what permission a user is missing (if they dont have the permission). How do i do that. Also i know that `{missing permission}` isnt the correct term but thats where i want the missing permission to be shown.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
      missing_perms_embed = discord.Embed(title = f":x: **You need {missing permission} permission to run this command**", color = 0xff0000)
      await ctx.send(embed = missing_perms_embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MissingPermissions). There is an attribute that will return a list of the permissions that are needed.

```py
discord.Embed(description=f":x: You need {', '.join(error.missing_perms)} permission(s) to run this command", color = 0xff0000)
```

FYI, I put the string as a description since emojis don't work in the title :)

Comment: Thanks, also i am able to put emojis in the title and it works. Does it not work for you?

Comment: @Phantom If I remember correctly it shouldn't (unless it's a unicode emoji). But description is still the best place to put it

Comment: Also remember to accept the answer if it helped you out ;)